# Parallel Recursive Bitonic Sort slower than Serial (OpenMP)

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

My OpenMP (C) parallel code is slower than the serial bitonic sort code and although I have done all the possible combinations I could think of, I can't find the problem.

Here is part of the code:

```
void recBitonicSortOpenMP( int lo, int cnt, int dir ) {
   if (  cnt >  1 ) {
         int k = cnt / 2;
         #pragma omp parallel sections 
         {

         #pragma omp section 
         recBitonicSortOpenMP( lo,     k, ASCENDING );

         #pragma omp section    
         recBitonicSortOpenMP( lo + k, k, DESCENDING );

         }
         bitonicMergeOpenMP( lo, cnt, dir );

   }

}
```

It is an implementation of Bitonic Sort.

Comment: For a proper explanation, the question requires a [mcve], system description, and actual performance observation. Generally - user `task`s for parallelizing recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For recursive problems like this use OpenMP tasks, not nested parallelism and sections. 
http://cs.umw.edu/~finlayson/class/fall16/cpsc425/notes/24-sorting.html gives you a good example to follow...

Comment: On the code shown in your link the `omp parallel` block appears to be nested (it is placed in the recursive function). Can this cause trouble if using `OMP_NESTED` for other parts of the code? I was expecting the parallel block to be outside the first call of the function, or using a different function for the top recursion level instead. Also, the slowdown that is discussed at the end of the page, can be alleviated by the use of the `final` task clause.

Comment: Yes, you are right, that code shouldn't be using nested parallelism (I should have read it in more detail before saying it is "a good example"). It ought to be structured to only enter parallelism at the outer level if no parallelism already exists (`omp_in_parallel()`), use taskwait for completion, and separate the outer instantiation from the recursive ones (though maybe that's not needed with the in parallel test).

Answer (score 0):

You should try to parallelize the imperative version of the algorithm. I think the recursive version is an inherently serial problem.

There are many pragmas useful to parallelize "For" cycles.

http://www.openmp.org/specifications/

Two version of the algorithm:

https://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/fall08/cps196.1/Pthreads/bitonic.c

Comment: I have already parallelized the imperative version and I have also parallelized the recursive one too, but using Cilk. Now I am trying to use OpenMP for parallelization.

Comment: " I have also parallelized the recursive one too, but using Cilk". Good, so you should find it relatively easy to yuse that style with OpenMP tasks :-)